Fallo en la implementacion del sdk de mercado pago
estos dias estuve intentando solucionar este error que me estaba apareciendo a la hora de implementar el sdk de mercadopago.

Y estas serian mis dependencias que agregue (la de mercadopago es la que me da el problema porque al sacarla me deja de tirar el error):
`
dependencies {
//Mercado Pago
implementation 'com.mercadopago:sdk-java:2.1.7'

//Maven
implementation 'org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:3.1.0'

}
`
Sinceramente no se que podria ser ya que busque por todos lados, actualice las versiones del gradle y el plugin, instale el maven, hice lo de las variables del entorno. Lo unico que no entendi bien fue lo de "maven install", ya que en la documentacion de mercadopago decia que lo tenia que poner en la terminal pero me tiraba un error que decia que no reconocia ese comando. Tambien lo puse en el cmd pero tambien me tiraba error.



Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Maven se encarga de descargar y administrar las dependencias de tu proyecto, es similar a Gradle, ya que ambos son sistemas de gestión de construcción y dependencias, por lo tanto, lo mejor sería que solo cuentes con uno de ellos para tu proyecto.
Sobre el comando 
maven install

 se encarga de compilar tu proyecto, crea el artefacto del proyecto y lo instala en tu repositorio local de Maven.
Para poder utilizar el comando tu proyecto idealmente debería de estar configurado para que Maven gestione las dependencias y no Gradle, las dependencias en Maven se colocan en un archivo pom.xml
Puedes obtener más información de como configurar tu proyecto para que utilice Maven en esta página: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html
Si consideras cambiar Gradle por Maven puedes buscar tus dependencias en Maven Repository: https://mvnrepository.com/

En mi caso yo actualizo dependencias haciendo click derecho en el pom.xml y yendo a la opción maven de ahi hago un clean install y si modificaste algo del pom se intentara actualizar ahi.
Si tenes intellij de este año es posible que tengas que hacerlo desde arriba a la derecha donde se ve una "M" de Maven como te muestro en la imagen:

